# Anyone have experience with Sphinx speech recognition?

Tags: speech-recognition, ivr, cmusphinx

Has anyone used the [Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/html/cmusphinx.php) speech recognition stack to build IVR applications?  I am looking for open source alternatives to the expensive and somewhat limiting choices from MSFT and others.  I have not been able to find a comprehensive package that ties open source speech/voip applications together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last I looked at Sphinx, it had issues with 8khz audio which resulted
in really poor performance.  There's not a lot of people talking about
successful deployments of Sphinx in real environments, but you might
be able to get it to work with some trailblazing effort.  See here for
more info:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki-Sphinx

The closest thing to open-source that really works is using LumenVox
with Asterisk.  Asterisk is the open-source PBX that you can use to
integrate with a VoIP service or gateway, or even the PSTN.  LumenVox
is a commercial speech engine that integrates with Asterisk:

http://www.asterisk.org
http://www.lumenvox.com
http://www.lumenvox.com/partners/digium/Asterisk.aspx

There's lots of people successfully using LumenVox with Asterisk.

Answer (score 2):

You could try integrating Sphinx with [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/):

- http://www.syednetworks.com/asterisk-integration-with-sphinx-voice-recognition-system
- http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Sphinx